# benefits for the program = benefits for the program's participants?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The purpose of this MOU is to clearly identify the roles and responsibilities of each party as they relate to the implementation of the United States Department of Agriculture (USDA) Food Stamp Program (FSP). The FSP is intended to help state agencies inform low-income households about the availability, eligibility requirements, applications procedures and **benefits for the program**.

Is this use of the preposition **for** natural? Is the intended meaning "benefits under the program", "benefits enjoyed by the low-income households enrolled in the program"?

Could it be that the preposition **for** is used because each of the terms "eligibility requirements", "application procedures" and "benefits" relates to the **program**? That is, because the authors of the sentence decided to link several terms to a single preposition phrase?

When I try to "hook up" each of these terms to the preposition phrase, this is what I get:

"Availability **for** the program" looks strange to me. I would use "availability **of** the program (in a specific location, say)".

"Eligibility requirement **for** the program" looks okay.

"Application procedures **for** the program" looks somewhat strange. A natural way would've been, it seems to me, "application procedures for the participation in the program".

"Benefits **for** the program" looks understandable within the context, but in another context it could've meant "benefits provided **to** the program" (not to the indigent families, but, say, to the agencies implementing the program)

Comment: Nope, it ain't.  The author picked a preposition that fit with 'procedures'.  Is 'applications' a typo? Would expect a singular there.

Comment: @TRomano: So "application procedures and benefits" is an integral phrase (benefits and procedures related to application)? (yes, "applications" could be a typo", but I copied the quote, not typed it, so it's a typo present in the original)

Comment: @TRomano: If "application procedures" and "benefits" are distinct terms, why not pick a preposition better suited to the last term used, that is, "benefits"?

Comment: No, I think not. The FSP is intended to help state agencies inform low-income households of the availability of the program  and its benefits; it also sets out the program's eligibility requirements and application procedures.

Comment: I reword to avoid situations where I'd have to pick a preposition that doesn't fit all of the items in the list.

Comment: @TRomano: I try to reword too in a similar fashion, that's why I wondered whether the authors were grammatical in their composition.

Comment: *applications procedures* is in the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FSP is intended to help state agencies inform low-income households about the

availability,
eligibility requirements,
applications procedures
and
benefits 
*for*
the program.

=

The FSP is intended to help state agencies inform low-income households about

the availability for,
the eligibility requirements for,
the applications procedures for
and
the benefits for
the program.

*for* is best approximated by *in regards to*, *as regards*, *regarding*, *with respect to*, *in relation to.*

See [M-W 7](http://i.word.com/idictionary/for), [ODO 2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for), [Collins 13](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for), [dictionary.com 10](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/For) and, [best for last](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/for?q=For), but you have to scroll down for *in relation to.*

Comment: Thank you, CarSmack! So **for** seems to fit every term in the list.

Comment: Availability *for*?

Comment: A company car may be *available for use* by managers.  We can talk about the car's  *availability for* managers. But we would be discussing the *availability of* the car.